# how to import without index at the ending url - vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, import

I'm trying to to configure vs-code to recognize and suggest imports without
index ending

```
foo (folder)
   - index (js file)
```

**current behavior:**

```
import './foo/index'
```

**expected behavior:**

```
import './foo'
```

I tried changing vs code settings but its still doesn`t work:

```
javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding: 'shortest',
typesciprt.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding: 'shortest'
```

-. Note I also use react and path intellisense if it matters

Have anyone ever encountered this problem ? I would be grateful for any help I could get

Comment: Can you give us the extension of you index file?

Comment: the extention is .js

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by installing the various plugins below.

Most of the time things just import by themselves as soon as I type the class name. Alternatively, a lightbulb appears that you can click on. Or you can push **F1**, and type "import..." and there are various options there too. I kinda use all of them. Also **F1** Implement for implementing an interface is helpful, but doesn't always work.

**List of Plugins**

- npm Intellisense
- ngrx for Angular 2 Snippets
- TypeScript Toolbox
- npm
- TsTools
- Angular Snippets (Version 9)
- Types auto installer
- Debugger for Chrome
- TypeScript Importer
- TypeScript Hero
- vscode-icons
- Add Angular Files

Comment: Thanks for the comment appreciate, its a lot of plugins which one is relevant for me?

Comment: NPM INTELLISENSE https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.npm-intellisense

Comment: its for npm modules, in my case its my files that I created

Comment: I know it is an extension not a npm module that you have to install with npm :)

Comment: Also you better start using NPM with the files you created because it will make your life a lot easier. use `npm init` to initialize an packate.json and then I believe you'll be able to use imports to folders without issues since it loads what config to use _es6, es5..._